# What is the difference between '\n' and std::endl

Tags: c++

Can someone explain the difference between:

```
std::cout << "stuff\n";
```

...and...:

```
std::cout << "stuff" << std::endl;
```

Comment: `endl` flushes the buffer. Easily found by searching :p [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4512631/645270) one (that's actually a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/645270) one).

Comment: You also meant `'\n'`, not `"\n"`. Something that is often overlooked when people jump straight to the "flush" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will generate the same characters (i.e. a carriage return), however `std::endl` will also flush the stream, which could have an impact on performance if over-used when generating large amounts of  output.